# 3D Viewer in WinDev

Tags: stl-format, windev

I am a student and I must develop an application with WinDev wich allow to display a 3D visualization of a STL file. This application must allow to add labels at specific positions in the frame (x, y, z).

I did researchs about it but the only conclusive research I've found is to create a complete 3D viewer except that I only have 12 weeks to do that.

I wanted to use OpenGL but I saw that OpenGL can only create basic component (cylinders, cubes, pyramids, ...) and it can't open an STL file to convert it on basic component (or just display the file)

After, I search if there is a library for WinDev (like a 3D Viewer) but I found nothing.

I found an OpenSource soft to see STL file (coded in C++), maybe there is something to export it (or a part) in WinDev (I use WinDev 17).

If someone have a solution for my problem...

Thank you, Jérémy L.

Comment: What are you calling a STL file ? Moreover you should know that OpenGL capabilities are far more advanced.

Comment: This a file .stl : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)

With OpenGL I found nothing about STL files, maybe if you know something ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Thingiview.js. It allows you to render a 3D image with javascript.

https://github.com/tbuser/thingiview.js?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter

You can view an example of a website using this library here:
http://www.3DTransform.com

Answer (score 0):

Your 12 weeks may be elapsed now, sorry to come here late.

I'm using Windev since a lot of time, and I'm working with 2D / 3D viewers since even more time, and if I know a thing it's that except for dealing with simple data and creating nice GUI, Windev is not what you'll want for managing 2D/3D engines.

Practical solutions each tend to embed .Net controls into your Windev GUI. I've done it with following frameworks :

- Ogre3D (a very long time ago : 2008 - 2009)
- Teigha (an AutoCAD framework, nice for dealing with 2D, and even for some simple 3D, but not really easy to use)
- XBim (it embeds a 3d Viewer which in fact is an HelixToolkit.Wpf control)
- A custom, full WPF, light weight 2D engine I've made, a day I needed to display shapes in a control with pan/zoom capabilities.

Windev let you embed easily dotNet controls, despite winforms controls being easier to embed than wpf ones, it's a pretty cool solution most of the time.

Remember : as long as you're able to build a .Net assemby that do what you want (display things or whatever else), even if it has native dependencies itself, you may be able to use it inside of your Windev application.